# Display Serial Numbers

Tags: php, mysql, sql

How to display Serial Numbers based  on the number raw count with mysql query result in my     html table.
Which help my table user count the no of record exist.How can I code this? I  have try to use

```
    <?php if(count($records) > 0) { ?>
<?php
            foreach ($records as $row){?>
```

but it shows error:

```
  <table border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="2" >
 <thead>
<tr>
 <th> Serial No </th>

    <th> Agent ID </th>
    <th> Name of Agent</th>
    <th> Agent Mobile</th>
    <th> Agent Card No</th>

    <th> POS Terminal </th>
    <th> APN Mobile No</th>
    <th> Update</th>
</tr>
 </thead>
  <tbody>
<?php
    include('connect.php');
    $result = $db->prepare("SELECT  `Agentid`,`agentname`,`phone`,             

     `meghna_c_no`, `pos_no`, `apn_mobile` FROM `agent` where `status`=2 
      ORDER BY  Agentid DESC");
    $result->execute();
    for($i=0; $row = $result->fetch(); $i++){
?>

<tr class="record">


    <td><?php echo $row['Agentid']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['agentname']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['phone']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['meghna_c_no']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['pos_no']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['apn_mobile']; ?></td>
    <td><a href="editform.php?Agentid=<?php echo $row['Agentid']; ?>"> 
        Insert </a>   </td>
</tr>

<?php
    }
?>

  </tbody>
  </table>
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Answer (score 2):

use a counter variable and increment it in each row like this

```
$result->execute();
$counter = 0; // initialize the counter
        for($i=0; $row = $result->fetch(); $i++){
$counter+=1; // increment the counter by 1
    ?>

    <tr class="record">

        <td><?php echo $counter; ?></td> <!-- display the counter -->
        <td><?php echo $row['Agentid']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['agentname']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['phone']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['meghna_c_no']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['pos_no']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['apn_mobile']; ?></td>
        <td><a href="editform.php?Agentid=<?php echo $row['Agentid']; ?>"> 
            Insert </a>   </td>
    </tr>

    <?php
        }
    ?>
```

you can also use your $i variable for it. like this

```
<td><?php echo ($i+1); ?></td>
```

instead of

```
<td><?php echo $counter; ?></td>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Use The $count Variable For Printing Serial Number, It Will continuously adding 1 Number Until The Loop Running.**

```
<table border="1">

    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th> Serial No </th>
        <th> Agent ID </th>
    <th> Name of Agent</th>
    <th> Agent Mobile</th>
    <th> Agent Card No</th>

    <th> POS Terminal </th>
    <th> APN Mobile No</th>
    <th> Update</th>
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
`<?php
    include('connect.php');


     $result = $db->prepare("SELECT  `Agentid`,`agentname`,`phone`,`meghna_c_no`, `pos_no`, `apn_mobile` FROM `agent` where `status`=2 
      ORDER BY  Agentid DESC");
    $result->execute();
    $count = 0; // Initializing The Counter
    for($i=0; $row = $result->fetch(); $i++)
    {
    $count++; //increment the counter ; ?>`
<tr class="record">

    <td><?php echo $count; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['Agentid']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['agentname']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['phone']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['meghna_c_no']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['pos_no']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['apn_mobile']; ?></td>
    <td><a href="editform.php?Agentid=<?php echo $row['Agentid']; ?>"> 
        Insert </a>   
    }
    </tr>
</td>
```

Answer (score 0):

In case you are using while loop, initiate $i = 0, followed by while loop, then echo ($i=$i+1); to print serial number.